# Unable to activate integration with Oauth 1.0

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.0

I have been trying to create my own external application using Oauth, but I get to filling out the details for the callback URL and Identity link URL (and the name), which creates fine, but when I go to activate the integration I get greated with a "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.", and the only error I get is from the debug.log file within Magento.

```
[2020-10-08 16:02:22] main.DEBUG: URI '/admin_13rc6p/admin/integration/tokensExchange/id/8/reauthorize/0/key/0ed0706f89d9950b82de796f028519b5f67df267cb337095fa255da0d52db82b/?form_key=hljjqv6G0SmuLm9g&_=1602172897038'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\TokensExchange) [] []
[2020-10-08 16:02:22] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Integration\Controller\Adminhtml\Integration\TokensExchange\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /var/www/magento-install.com/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []
```

(I replaced my domain with magento-install.com)

I have followed the guides on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html, but still no luck with getting it to activate.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

Got late, but hope this solution will help to others.
Getting same above issue on Magento 2.4.2 with Klaviyo Integration.

**Solution:**

/vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/TokensExchange.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class TokensExchange extends Integration implements HttpPostActionInterface,HttpGetActionInterface
```

Added additional interface `HttpGetActionInterface`
Please override this file to local

Thanks,

Comment: looks like this is fixed in 2.4.2-develop https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/68d20230ca9d6198fa3093eb174e24aff47b1646#comments